# Анализ дамп-файла с помощью библиотеки Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime

Tags: c#

У потоков есть поле BlockingObjects. Предполагаю, что это объекты блокирующие работу потока(ов). Но не могу найти более подробную информацию о том, что за объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вот такое решение.
У объекта "BlockingObject" есть поле "Object". Фактически, это адрес в памяти.
Остается только поискать этот объект в куче. Напишу все решение, чтоб было понятнее.

```
using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.LoadCrashDump(dmpFile))
{
    var runtime = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0].CreateRuntime();
    var heap = runtime.GetHeap();
    foreach (var thread in runtime.Threads)
    {
        //Поиск потоков, находящихся в режиме ожидания (по сути зависших)
        if (thread.BlockingObjects != null && thread.BlockingObjects.Count > 0)
        {
            //Определение адреса объекта, связанного с блокировкой
            var blockingObject = thread.BlockingObjects[0].Object;
            //Извлекается тип объекта из кучи
            var curType = heap.GetObjectType(blockingObject);
            //Перебираются все поля экземпляра этого типа
            foreach (var field in curType.Fields)
            {
                //Имя поля
                var fieldName = field.Name;
                //Значение поля
                var fieldValue = field.GetValue(blockingObject);
                //Тип поля
                var fieldType = field.Type;
            }
        }
    }
}
```